# SSVNC and Terminal commands

Tags: terminal

I want to launch SSVNC on Mac OSX from the terminal. 
I want it to connect to a UVNC repeater server and match the pairing ID's to allow a VNC session. 
I can do this with the GUI and it works fine. But I want to compile it from a script and launch it from there.

Settings:
VNC Host:Display = :1

VNC Password =

Proxy/Gateway = repeater://server1.domain.com:3467+ID:12345

The bit I am having issue with is telling it not to use SSL or Fetch certs. It always tried to fetch the cert and errors. Setting this to none in the GUI works like a charm.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Az